# How do i deal with textual images that need to show the translated version?

Tags: django, internationalization

What's the best way to deal with i18n and text images?

I have a number of images that have text in them that need to be swapped out for the right version for each language. i.e. I have a "header.gif" with the text in English, then another "header.gif" with the text in French.

what's the easiest way to say

```
if my image exists in the current language:
    show the image
else
    show the english image
```

I'm thinking a middleware that can check for every img tag, check if the requested image is available in the current language, if so, change the img tag to show it, if not, don't.

My other thought was to simply enclose the image reference in a `{% trans ... %}` tag and change the url in the .po file

or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a middleware to parse the html before it is rendered to check for images in a `locale` folder inside my media folder. If they exist, then change the src tag, if not, keep it as is:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    # check if we should try this here
    if self.inject_media(request, response):
        media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL
        lang = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
        media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        string = smart_unicode(response.content)
        no_case = string.lower()
        find = "%s[a-z0-9\.\_\/]+" % media_url
        pattern = re.compile(find)
        matches = pattern.findall(no_case)
        base_path = "%slocale/%s/" % (media_root, lang)
        for m in matches:
            p = m.replace(media_url, base_path)
            if os.path.isfile(p):
                url = m.replace(media_url, "%slocale/%s/" % (media_url, lang))           
                string = string.replace(m, url)

        response.content = string
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try solving this by defining some models for images:

```
class ImageTitle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length = 100) 

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(ImageTitle)
    image = models.ImageField('Image')
    language = models.CharField('Language', max_length = 100)
```

Define some function for rendering the image according to the language setting.

Comment: Then you may follow some sort of naming procedure yourself like for header you may keep "header_lang.jpg" and then while calling frm templates use /[url]/header_{{ language }}.jpg as the image source.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make subfolders in your media directory

/static/img/es_ES
/static/img/en_EN

And dispatch the correct image depending on the requested language with a {% media_url %} custom template tag.